# CSS Rule Set Selector

Tags: css

I recently completed an assignment that had this question:

> Within a CSS rule set, a selector includes
>
> 1. a selector and a declaration block
> 2. a selector and a value
> 3. a property and a selector
> 4. a property and a value

The correct answer given was option 4.

I don't quite agree with the answer. In fact, none of the answers seem correct to me, but I wanted to make sure I wasn't misunderstanding the question.

I would appreciate if someone could confirm if the question is flawed or explain  the answer if it was indeed correct.

Comment: A CSS rule is  ... indeed a rule with a property and a value. Without a property and a value, you do not have a rule at all., hence no set as well ... 4 is indeed the correct answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In CSS A "rule set" (or just "rule") consist of a "selector" and a "declaration block".

A "declaration block" consists of "declarations" between curly brackets.

Each "declaration" contains a "property", a colon and a "value" separated from each other within the "declaration block" by a semi-colon.

So you are right. None of the options match, and option 4 is the definition of a "declaration", not a "selector".

See [4.1.7 Rule sets, declaration blocks, and selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#rule-sets) and [4.1.8 Declarations and properties](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#declaration)

Answer (score 4):

As [W3C (World Wide Web Consortium](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/) says, a selectors are:

> patterns that match against elements in a tree, and as such form one of several technologies that can be used to select nodes in an XML document.

Mozilla Developer Network describes CSS rules [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors).

Indeed, a **CSS rule** includes a selector, a property and a value.

Personally, the sintax of the question is a bit awkward, but it is not flawed.

Comment: Agreed, that should've been worded better, still number 4 is the only one out of those options that is true.

Answer (score 1):

It's correct:

`div { margin: 0; }`

1. The whole line is a rule set
2. div is a selector
3. margin is a property
4. 0 is a value

Comment: But doesn't that read "a selector includes a property and a value" when the selector should just be `div`? The rule set is the one that includes a selector and zero or more property and value pairs inside the declaration block.

Comment: Yes, in order to be a CSS rule set the selector (div) requires a property (margin) and value (0)